# Proper tubular tire installation

Tags: tire, installation

I'm trying to install a new tubular tire once again. The problem is every time I do this I always get it wrong because I always have this area (let's say 10-15cm each way) around the tire's valve that kinda extends a bit so when I ride after the installation I always have this wobbling, which you barely notice when you ride slow but when you speed up it's getting kinda annoying and a bit scary.

I watched A LOT of videos on youtube, I used different kinds of cements, tape and ways of installation, but I can't get it right for some reason. Maybe it's because I use cheap tires or I need to do something after the tire is settled on the rim?

Please tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe pay a shop to do it once and find out if you have bad tire or rim.  Why go tubular if you are going to cheap it?

Comment: @Frisbee I thought about getting it to the shop, and It's not about cheaping it. I like to do everything with my hands and I like to make things perfectly good too, so it's more about learning the right technique than cheaping.

Comment: "Maybe it's because I use cheap tires"

Comment: @Frisbee Well it would be just because of the cheap tires the whole internet would swarm with bad testimonials about cheap tires, yet people use them, I assume, way more than expensive ones, without complaining. I still think I'm the one who's doing something wrong. Again I plan to go expensive ones, but I need to be sure that I can install them properly.

Comment: The likely problem is that either your tires are bad or you can't install them and money can solve both. The question says that the area around "nipple kinda extends", can you show that?

Comment: In this particular case, I ride clinchers. A good clincher costs about as much as cheapest tubular and is easy to mount. I may switch to tubulars when I have a sponsor to pay for them and team mechanic to install them.

Comment: @ojs find someone who pays you everything including a team mechanic is a very good option. I can't argue with that. Put it as an answer, I'll definitely upvote

Comment: You say you have an area 10-15 cm each side of the valve that wobbles? How close to the valve are you gluing or taping? I always leave a gap there but it is not nearly that wide, probably around 3 cm each side of the valve.

Comment: @ojs Sure but the stability of the ride, the cornering, the rolling resistance and the comfort level are all significantly better with tubbies. Worth the cost by far.

Comment: Often, this problem is caused by the double layers of cloth where it wraps under the valve. You have to be extra careful to fully seat the valve into the rim and stretch the tire away from there as you install it around the rim. Are you using glue or Tufo tape to install the tires? If the difference is minor, it will settle as you ride. (Minor enough that you don't feel it in the saddle, it's only a visible problem. )

Comment: If you can feel it in the ride, it can be cheap tires where they didn't take enough care to make the layering around the valve smooth, or it can be that your rims don't have enough of a trough to allow the tire to fully seat in the rim.

Comment: Might be worth going to a shop and paying them (if necessary) to _watch you_ do it to see if an expert eye can see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have got a loose area of tyre next to the valve, you need to 'distribute' this looseness to some other part of the rim.

Put a screw-driver across the rim under the tyre, and roll it around the rim away from the valve.   The screwdriver will slip on the metal rim, but grip the tyre, so it will revolve.

Do this for both loose areas, each side of the valve, before you blow the tyre up.   Once up to pressure, the tyre should run true, and be well stuck.
Cheers...  Pete

Comment: Won't that break the glue? I'm not convinced that the screwdriver will slide on the glue-covered rim as easily as your description suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the used to happen to me. I've found that the tube is not evenly distributed in the tire.  Not surprising, with all the coaxing, levering, and finnagling to get the bead onto the rim.

What works for me is to massage/knead the tire.  Yeah, sounds weird.  So once you have gotten the tire into the rim, inflate the tube just a little bit.  Then massage the tire, as one would do to bread dough.  Maybe repeat this a couple of more times.  I just do this once, myself.

Oh- and make sure the powdery stuff on the tube is present.  This helps the tube move around as needed during inflation.  Without the powder, the tube will grip onto the tire and won't expand and distribute evenly.